# SQL Server date range and outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to do a simple aggregate query to total some results for users in a date range. I want to select ALL users, and if they don't have appropriate records the query should just return 0 for them.

The problem is, even with a right outer join on the table selecting the user IDs it only selects users that exist in that date range of the left table...

Here is the query:

```
select B.fld_strcode, sum(ISNULL(fld_val, 0)) as res
from tbl_transproc A right outer join tbl_pr B on A.fld_int_id = B.fld_auto_int_id
where A.fld_dtmservicedate between '2012-04-01' and '2012-05-01'
and B.fld_bytprtypeid = 1
group by B.fld_strcode
```

This query returns 13 rows. The query to select just the IDs(fld_strcode) returns 25 unique results. I want it to return 25 rows (for each ID), and the ones without values just to have a value of 0. If I take out the date range (go through all results in the table) then it works for all users, which makes sense because over all time all users will have at least one record in the table. Some users won't have a record for some months, and when this is the case I need it to just return 0 for them.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that.

Comment: `2012-04-01` is ambiguous - is that April 1st or fourth of January 2012? Your second date suffers from the same issue.

Comment: Yea, you are right. It should still select all of the IDs from the user table though..

Comment: My point is that this ambiguity may be what is causing your issue (SQL Server may interpret the date differently from what you meant).

Answer (score 3):

When filtering outer join one must remember to do it in join itself, otherwise one ends up with masked inner join:

```
select B.fld_strcode, sum(ISNULL(fld_val, 0)) as res
  from tbl_transproc A 
 right outer join tbl_pr B 
    on A.fld_int_id = B.fld_auto_int_id
   AND A.fld_dtmservicedate between '2012-04-01' and '2012-05-01'
 where B.fld_bytprtypeid = 1
 group by B.fld_strcode
```

I would switch tables so I get left join, because in more complex queries it gets unreadable, especially if you mix right and left joins, as query designer likes to do.

Comment: Beat me to it... +1 for always using LEFT JOINS